# Unable to put logic for formatting the date

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to implement a format rule where i have an input string of date "1918-12-31T24:00:00Z" and i need to show it as "1/1/1918". Implemented below code:

Please Note that value relement="1918-12-31T24:00:00Z" or in similar format.

```
    <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="not($relement)"/>
            <xsl:when test="$relement = ''"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="rdate" select="substring-before('$relement','T')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($rdate,'-'),'-')"/>                                       
                <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after($rdate,'-'),'-')"/>  
                <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($rdate,'-')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-after('$relement','T')"/>                 

                <xsl:variable name="lastdate">  
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$month = 2 and not($year mod 4) and ($year mod 100 or not($year mod 400))">
                    <xsl:value-of select="29"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring('312831303130313130313031', 2 * $month - 1,2)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="dayadj">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($time,'24:00:00Z')">  2011-12-31T24:00:00Z
                    <xsl:value-of select="$day + '1'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
                </xsl:otherwise> 
                </xsl:choose>  
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="finaldate">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$dayadj > $lastdate and ($month = 12)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('1','/','1','/',$year + '1')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$dayadj > $lastdate and ($month != 12)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month + '1','/','1','/',$year)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month,'/',$dayadj,'/',$year)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable> 
          <xsl:attribute name="internal"><xsl:value-of select="$arg1/@internal"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$finaldate"/> 
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The above code is failing in giving output, as I am not able to find the logic to apply the validation on last day of the month and year as well.

The incorrect output I am getting is : "////" in all the cases.

Comment: (at) Filburt nice edit ;)

Comment: Is it possible to include some logic within <xsl:choose> block ?

Comment: See http://soajagat.blogspot.com/2009/06/xpath-10-datetime-nightmares.html

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) There are two places where you refer to the `$relement` variable, but you have it quoted:  `'$relement'`.  This is using the literal string "`$relement`" instead of referring to the variable.

2) You have the seemingly random date `2011-12-31T24:00:00Z` at the end of the line starting with `<xsl:when test="contains($time,'24:00:00Z')">`

See this [XSLTCake](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/eDzG3q) demo for a working version.